# Error: Could not find or load main class thredds.catalog.dl.ADNWriter is coming

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement)
        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
        result.add(obj);
    else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
        for (Object child : children) {
            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException {
    String inputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\sugreev.sharma\\Desktop\\BMS\\test\\Ireland CTAg - Authority and CTI_July 2018.docx";
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(inputfilepath));
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    List<Object> paragraphs = getAllElementFromObject(mainDocumentPart, P.class);
    for (Object par : paragraphs) {
        P p = (P) par;
        // Get all the runs in the paragraph
        List<Object> allRuns = p.getContent();
        for (Object run : allRuns) {
            R r = (R) run;
            // Get the Text in the Run
            List<Object> allText = r.getContent();
            for (Object text : allText) {
                Text txt = (Text) text;
                System.out.println("--> " + txt.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, which I am using in project.
I am using docx4j for docx processing.

Comment: Can you paste the full code of the class? Is this the code of ADNWriter class or that is a separate class altogether?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved this problem today.